# Magento 2 All Links Give 404 Not Found

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, migration, 404-page

So I’ve just migrated a magento store over to a new server.

Gone through the standard setup procedure of copying the html files, updating the host url in the database and modifying my db details in **app/etc/env.php.**

***I’ve also disabled the dev static signing option to prevent the issue where magento looks for assets in pub/static/versionxxxx..***

The issue I’m having now is that my index.php loads fine and all looks how it should.

However clicking any link, **for example a href to /scarves.php gives me a 404.** Not quite sure why as obviously all of my pub and php files are not in the index folder.

How can I go about fixing this, does magento rewrite these links internally somehow?

Comment: try to run the magento re indexing again on the server.

Comment: I’ve ran reindexing quite a few times. I’m new to magento but how is it supposed to work when you click a link. Because all of these php pages are not under /<path> and Apache is throwing a 404 because of this.

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite

Comment: I’ve also turned on Rewrite mode for apache, can you provide some insight into how the expected behaviour should work for rewriting the links?

Comment: @Adam, No need to do any. Just take fresh .htaccess file and upload. Take backup first

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced this problem you need to add these lines in your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Will that not have a similar issue, if for example I navigate to “products.php” then that rule would rewrite the path to “index.php/products.php” which apache wouldn’t be able to recognise as its not a valid file path. So how would that end up working?